# Missing workflow task

Tags: workflow, email, tasks

A user is receiving an email for task that is overdue.  The document that it relates to has been deleted.  I have searched for the task and looked in the task history but I can not find it.  Any suggestions how to track it down or stop the email?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to clear the config cache followed this knowledge base article, restart the SharePoint Timer and wait for the effect.

[KB Article by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939308)

You can also run the following query against the Web Application content database to determine if there is an orphaned item in the table.
Select * from SecheduledWorkItems where ID=’GUID’

If the item and associated workflow tasks are removed while the workflow is still running, it will leave out the related records in ScheduledWorkItems table which timer services checks regularly hence sending out the overdue notification emails at the time. It is because the workflows associated with the document were not yet completed at the time and they need to monitor the status of those tasks.

Sometimes this may not work. Once we had this same issue, we had a rule written in outlook for the particular user and routed it to the deleted items folder.